# Semicircular family

Tags: probability

I have a question which seems pretty obvious but I would like to know if you have a semicircular family of covariance $C$ (Suppose to be definite positive symmetric) living in a tracial Von Neumann algebra, denote $C^{\frac{1}{2}}$the square root of the covariance matrix, suppose I have another n-tuple of free-semicircular $S_1$, is $C^{\frac{1}{2}}S_1$a semicircular family of covariance $C$. The classical counterpart is well known because when you have a Gaussian vector of covariance $C$ (centered for example) $C^{\frac{1}{2}}Z$ where $Z$is a standard multi variate Gaussian is Gaussian of covariance $C$.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Use MathJax formatting for mathematical expressions.